Agency of assassins who have to kill each other
I have wanted to identify a film that I watched a long time ago for a long time, but my many researches on Google have not yet be able to find it. Could you please help me with that ? The elements I remember on this movie:

It is some kind of an official agency of assassins.
Their contract is terminated somehow, I think that that the agency is not needed anymore, and they have to kill each other in order to escape the basement.
Their is a big number of imaginative deaths.
It is not so recent, before 2010 I think.
There are great dialogs between the characters.
I don't remember the country, but it is probably american.
I did not find it on google, so I guess it is not a famous movie.


It is a great movie, really funny and distracting and I liked it a lot. So I recommend everyone to watch this movie, if you like movies like Battle Royal or the Tournament or just the first Hunger Games.

This one (Operation: Endgame)?

Yes, there it is ! Thank you so much ! You should answer it officially so I can validate your answer ! I do not understand why this movie is such down-voted...

No problem. :) Glad you found it.

Sorry for the duplicate, I just remembered so few things that I wasn't able to find this other thread :)
